# How to Setup Redundant DB for ExpressionEngine?

Tags: database, settings

Does anyone have an experience setting up ExpressionEngine with a redundant db architecture? Per corporate requirements, I must host the EE site within our corporate server structure.

What is the best method for setting up redundant data server? I've read other articles that say EE doesn't work in a Master -> Master replication. I've read other articles that say you can use CI to connect to multiple DB but nothing that is tested for EE.

Any other options?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need redundancy for failover? Or do you need it for load balancing? Or, for both?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same requirements in my location for a set of sites. Ours was for both redundancy and failover. I ended up with a customized version of Erik's master config for FocusLab here: https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config

Once I established the settings that worked for my needs, I built out a bootstrap install to make updates much easier too.

Comment: What exactly did you add to the config to allow for redundancy?

Comment: I'm not seeing how this answer applies to the question.